# CreateProcess error=2 when the path really exists

Tags: java, processbuilder

I'm working with the java ProcessBuilder class to start an instance of nmap on my windows workstation.

The following code produces an exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap\nmap.exe -T4 -A -v --max-scan-delay 0ms --min-rate 1000000 --max-retries 0  -oX -  192.168.1.1 ": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

The value of command is:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap\nmap.exe -T4 -A -v --max-scan-delay 0ms --min-rate 1000000 --max-retries 0  -oX -  192.168.1.1
```

Running the command is generated right in a command window executes properly.

Any ideas?

```
String command = this.getCommand().toString();
        ExecutionResults results = new ExecutionResults();
        ProcessBuilder procBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(new String[]{command.toString()});

        try {
            Process e = procBuilder.start();
            results.setErrors(this.convertStream(e.getErrorStream()));
            results.setOutput(this.convertStream(e.getInputStream()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the whole command (including parameters) as a single parameter of the ProcessBuilder constructor. It takes a String[], where the first item should be the path to the executable, and the other items should be the parameters. Try

```
command.split(" ")
```

instead of

```
new String[]{command.toString()}
```

Edit: I see that you have spaces in your path, that will break it :( you could try splitting the executable path and the arguments into two strings. And the constructor argument will be a String[] containing the path itself as the first item and then an array of the parameters split by space.

OR: if you don't mind not using the ProcessBuilder.. this is much simpler:

```
Process e = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is simple from the exception itself,

> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap\nmap.exe -T4 -A -v --max-scan-delay 0ms --min-rate 1000000 --max-retries 0  -oX -  192.168.1.1 ": CreateProcess error=2, The system

Process builder taking the whole line thinking it is as an executable and trying to run that. Just use the below example,

```
ProcessBuilder procBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(new String[]{"C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap\nmap.exe"});
    procBuilder.start();
```

This will work fine. So this is not an issue what you think that java is unable to find the executable. It is taking whole line as an executable. Better you do like below,

```
ProcessBuilder procBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(new String[]{"C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap\nmap.exe", "-T4", "-A"}); //add all params
procBuilder.start();
```

Try this, it should work fine

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers have indicated, your immediate problem is that you're passing an entire command line as if it's the name of a program to run. `CreateProcess` is looking for a program named "C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap\nmap.exe -T4 -A etc" and failing to find it.

If you have a string containing a command to run (a program name with arguments, redirection, and so on), then the simplest way to run it is to launch it via the command line processor. Here's a simple example of doing that:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String command = "dir /w";
    ProcessBuilder procBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(new String[]{"cmd", "/c", command});
    procBuilder.redirectInput(Redirect.INHERIT);
    procBuilder.redirectOutput(Redirect.INHERIT);
    procBuilder.redirectError(Redirect.INHERIT);
    Process p = procBuilder.start();
    int ecode = p.waitFor();
    System.err.println("Exit code " + ecode);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be because of a couple of reasons from my experience

1. Firewall would be removed certain files necessary for the installer. So would suggest to uninstall and reinstall
2. Can also be because of spaces in the folder path, would suggest to install in new folder which does not have spaces in the path.